# MVC Routing with Language Variant in Sitecore

Tags: mvc, multilingual, routing

I have MVC Routing issue in Sitecore. I have the following route in myRegisterRoutes() method. For this method I need to add language variant since I have enabled language fallback. Could some please help in this.

1. For English: http://xyz.com/api/sitecore/Forms/SubmitForm
2. For German: http://xyz.com/de-DE/api/sitecore/Forms/SubmitForm

Route map:

```
routes.MapRoute("FormsApi", "api/sitecore/Forms/SubmitForm",
    new { controller = "Forms", action = "SubmitForm" });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add your language as a parameter to the route. Something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("FormsApiWithLanguage",
    "{languageCode}/api/sitecore/Forms/SubmitForm",
    new { controller = "Forms", action = "SubmitForm", languageCode = "en" }
    );
```

I'm just setting a default language code there with the `"en"` - now your language code would be passed into your action as a param:

```
public ActionResult SubmitForm(string languageCode) 
{
}
```

If that doesn't work, you could append the language code to the *end* of the route instead of the start.

Comment: Thanks, this solution working fine when I am assigning in static value to languageCode. My requirement is to get Sitecore.Context.Language in RegiterRoute() method, but here I am not getting the  Sitecore.Context.Language.

So how can i get Sitecore.Context.Language in Routing?

Thanks for help so far..